# Spring authorization: cannot access resource server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

There are 2 modules in my project: auth-server and resource-server

These are project files.
https://github.com/LovelyCatEx/new-oauth2

Now the steps...
1.Get Code
Access
`http://127.0.0.1:9500/oauth2/authorize?client_id=messaging-client&response_type=code&scope=message.read&redirect_uri=http://www.google.com`

2. Get Token
   Redirected to:
   https://www.google.com/?code=QvT3hI3vJcTWJY_C29qVZH3R1_dtmh2DC7wN6hkcc-3LoNCutgkD_EGVHa-RcjxjdC7gG0dPSYYwAOuxv6LmjA_tEuV-A3CGst4MD44I6QDYjwX4GdKcJWxp7gy7Gg6E

```
POST: localhost:9000/oauth2/token

grant_type: authorization_code
code: ......
redirect_uri: http://www.google.com

Base Auth:

username: messaging-client
password: secret
```

And the token is:
{
"access_token": "token here",
"refresh_token": "......",
"scope": "message.read",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 299
}

3. Access Resource Server

Now I could access localhost:9600/user/info with token, but console outputs:

```
**org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderInitializationException: Failed to lazily resolve the supplied JwtDecoder instance**
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://127.0.0.1:9500"**
**Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>] and content type [text/html;charset=UTF-8]**
```

I have searched many answers but all not work...

Project files...
https://github.com/LovelyCatEx/new-oauth2

https://github.com/LovelyCatEx/new-oauth2

https://github.com/LovelyCatEx/new-oauth2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is all my project (In description above), what's more should I provide....https://github.com/LovelyCatEx/new-oauth2